# Formatting HTML input text product key

Tags: javascript, html, input, format

Im working on a website that creates an unattended XML file for Windows 7/8.

I have made a "Product key" text input where users can put in their product key and it will add it to the XML so they do not get prompted for it during installation.

This is what I have so far:

```
<td>Product Key:</td>
<td><input id="ProductKey1" size="5" maxlength="5" type="text">-<input id="ProductKey2" maxlength="5" size="5" type="text">-<input id="ProductKey3" maxlength="5" size="5" type="text">-<input id="ProductKey4" maxlength="5" size="5" type="text">-<input id="ProductKey5" maxlength="5" size="5" type="text"></td>
```

I have basically added 5 text inputs with a max length of 5 characters and each field is separated by a "-".

What I would like to do is have one longer field for the product key and have it insert the "-" after every 5 characters. What would be the easiest way to implement this with javascript?

Comment: Did you try something? http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 2):

You can simulate dashes, placing it on input field and adding onkeyup control to add spaces, or jquery.maskedinput: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. But what I would do is "substr" the string at every 5 caracters. I would do this like this:

```
function split_product_key(t) {
    // How many characters in string
    var length = t.length;
    // How many "5 chars length strings" is there in your string
    var loop = Math.ceil(length/5);
    // Create the output.
    var output = '';
    for (var i =1; i<=loop; i++) {
        // Getting the 5 chars substr
        output += t.substr((i*5),5) + '-';
    }
    // Removing the last "-"
    output = output.substr(0, output.length-1);
    return output;
}
```

Then all you have to do is get the product key the user entered and pass it throught "split_product_key" like this:
var splitted_product_key = split_product_key(original_product_key);
If you want to update the values in real time, just add a change even on the input and make the input value split_product_key(current_input_value)
I Hope this is clear, and I hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

```
function split_product_key(t) {
    t = t.toUpperCase();
    var key = t.replace(/([\w]{4})([\w]{4})([\w]{4})([\w]{4})/, function(match, p1, p2, p3, p4, offset, string){
        return [p1, p2, p3, p4].join('-');
    });
    return key;
}
```

This one used regex to make 16 digit string look like 'NLEB-8KPR-RZR1-QWJF', edit the regex part to change the pattern. Also, this is an old post, but I searched for a simple solution and this is it.